# Pass month name dynamically in AWK (GNU) with control statement

Tags: bash, variables, hadoop, awk, gnu

Hi I'm trying out below command to match month and day (of 6 days ago, which is Jun 29) to search a directory using AWK, but the result is always '0' instead it is supposed to be around 1800.

```
ls -ltr /test/output|awk  -v month="$(date --date="6 days ago" +"\"%b\"")", -v day="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d)"  '$6 ==month && $7==day {print $9}'|wc -l
```

tried this also

```
ls -ltr /test/output|awk  -v month="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%b)", -v day="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d)"  '$6 ==month && $7==day {print $9}'|wc -l
```

but it is working if I hardcode Month

```
ls -ltr /test/output|awk  -v month="$(date --date="6 days ago" +"\"%b\"")", -v day="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d)"  '$6 =="Jun" && $7==day {print $9}'|wc -l
```

Please suggest what I'm missing in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quotation marks in your month variable and so use:

```
date --date="6 days ago" +\%b
```

Alternatively, in awk, refer to the month with:

```
gensub("\"","","g",month)
```

I've notices that you also have a comma between the two variable assignments (-v) which needs to be removed. The complete solution is:

```
ls -ltr /test/output|awk  -v month="$(date --date="6 days ago" +\%b)" -v day="$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d)"  '$6 ==month && $7==day {print $9}'|wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use your awk filter query, but I could not make it to work.

I solved your problem by rewriting the query and using `grep` with a constructed date string to filter instead of `awk`.

```
ls -ltr |egrep "$(date --date="6 days ago" +%b) +$(date --date="6 days ago" +%d | sed 's/^0*//')" |awk '{print $9}'|wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out another approach to count.

```
yesterday_date=`date --date="6 days ago" +'%Y%m%d'`
start_date=${yesterday_date}"0000"
end_date=${yesterday_date}"2359"
temp_start_date_file=$HOME/tmpstartfile
temp_end_date_file=$HOME/tmpendfile
touch -t $start_date ${temp_start_date_file}
touch -t $end_date ${temp_end_date_file}

cd /test/output
find . -type f -newer ${temp_start_date_file} ! -newer ${temp_end_date_file} -ls | wc -l
```